# ASP.NET Razor C# appearing as text when publishing via file system with custom domain

Tags: filesystems, web-deployment, mime-types, razor-pages

I have a CSHTML web page in which a user completes a survey in a form (with method post) block and there's c# razor code that is adding the answers to the survey into an SQL server database. Via file system, I have published the website with a custom domain, but for some reason, when I browse to the link with the survey, all the c# razor code is visible at the bottom of the page. I'm not sure how to hide that code.

Here is an image of what the webpage looks like

[image: error]
I tried submitting the survey regardless of what was visible at the bottom, and got the following error.

HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     StaticFileModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070001
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

Comment: I can see the image link is not really working in the original post, so here it is - https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpwzb5bl9fqaf7l/iis%20issue.PNG?dl=0

Comment: can anyone help me at all??

Comment: You would need to post at least some of your cshtml page to say what the issue is. Try to get small bits working and add on to it. If you run into issues then you can more easily figure out what is not working

Comment: Brad, please refer to the image link in my first comment. The image best describes what exactly I'm seeing when I access the custom domain on Chrome after publishing via file system

Comment: The image just show the end result not what is behind the page. To run code on a page it needs to be in @{...} block. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2